# Performing classification when the potential options of classes are different for every data row/user

Tags: time-series, classification, prediction, multi-class

I have a problem that I am trying to solve using ML but am not able to determine techniques, hence asking for advice. Appreciate your urgent response!

I have a dataset of several users. Each user has 2 other important features (others are critical hence I can’t reveal them) – a timestamp/date and a specific location. My task is to predict the location the user will be at a specific point in time. At test time, I will be given only a range of 1 hour (eg. 4-5 PM, 1-2 AM etc.) and a user ID. I will have to predict the specific location. What is confusing me about this problem is that the locations are discrete, limited and different for different users (I can’t clearly see it as a classification/prediction problem). For example, user A can be only at 3 discrete locations at any time of the day (office, home, market) but user B can be at 4 discrete locations at any time of the day (Singapore, Seattle, Bangalore, Atlanta). Note that there is no overlap in the choices of locations for every user. The above classes are just examples and not representative of the actual dataset – the main idea is that the classes are discrete, countable and different for different for every user (next to no overlap). What techniques/papers/code repositories have you read to solve such problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you need to build a model for each person, training only on data from that individual. A model learned for user A to predict Office or Home won't have any applicability for user B to predict Singapore or Seattle. You can use the same model-building method for each person, but there will be a unique model for each person.

Comment: Thanks! My concern is that there is under 10 data points per customer on average so I'm not sure how much a learner might learn on such an offline dataset before going into production.